# Calculating $T^*T$ when $T$ have direct sum codomain

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

Let \begin{equation*} \bigoplus_{ \ell_2} K_n :=  \{ (x_1,x_2,\cdots) \in \bigoplus_{n=1}^\infty : x_n \in K_n, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} || x_n ||^2 <\infty \} \end{equation*}
where $K_n$ are Hilbert Spaces. It is clear that $\bigoplus_{ \ell_2} K_n$ is also a Hilbert space. Let be $H$ another Hilbert space, and the bounded operator \begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
 T & : H \rightarrow \bigoplus_{ \ell_2} K_n \\ 
   & x \mapsto (T_1 x,T_2 x, \cdots) 
\end{split} 
\end{equation*}
where $T_n = \pi_n \circ T$ and $\pi_n$ are the canonical projections.

We have that $T^* = T^* \circ \pi_n^* = T^* \circ j_n$, where $j_n : K_n \rightarrow  \bigoplus_{ \ell_2} K_n$ is the canonical inclusion (see [Adjoint of projection onto direct sum of Hilbert spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2692788/adjoint-of-projection-onto-direct-sum-of-hilbert-spaces))

I tried to prove that \begin{equation*} T^*T = \sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n^* T_n.
\end{equation*} 
This is my attempt:

Let $x \in H$.

We have \begin{equation*} \begin{split} \sum_{n=1}^\infty T_n^* T_n x & = \sum_{n=1}^\infty T^* j_n \pi_n Tx = T^*  \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty j_n \pi_n (T_1x,T_2x,\cdots) \right) \\ & = T^*\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty j_n(y_n)\right) = T^* \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty (0,\cdots,0,T_nx,0, \cdots) \right) \\ & = T^*(T_1x,T_2x,\cdots) = T^*Tx.
\end{split}
 \end{equation*}
Is my proof right? Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the second sum it should be $T^* j_n\pi_n T$ and not $T^*j_n\pi_nT^*$. Also I'm not sure why you define $Tx=(y_1,y_2,\ldots)$ when you could just write $(T_1x,T_2x,\ldots)$ so it's more clear what happens in each step. In principle this looks good to me tho.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you don't address is that of the series. A very important fact that is often overlooked, is that a series is a *limit* of partial sums, and a limit implies an underlying topology. But you don't say which topology.

What convergence do you consider on $\sum_n T_n^*T_n$? What about all the other sums in your reasoning? At the beginning of your reasoning your took $T^*$ out of the sum; that amounts to exchange it with the limit, so you are assuming that $T^*$ is continuous in whichever topology you are using for the sum.